# Apache configuration for Reactjs application and Symfony Api on the same domain

Tags: reactjs, apache, symfony

I'm trying to set up a front project (Reactjs) with an Api (Symfony 5) on the same domain.
But i have a problem with my api routes.

**My config under `/etc/apache2/sites-available/app.conf`**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.com
    ServerAlias app.com www.app.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/app-front/build/"
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    Alias "/api" "/var/www/app-back/public"

    <Directory "/var/www/app-front/build/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/app-back/public>
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All

        #FallbackResource index.php
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
        #RewriteRule "^/api(/.*)" "/api/api$1"
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/app-back/public/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**My `config/routes/annotation.yml` under my Symfony project :**

```
controllers:
    prefix: /api
    resource: ../../src/Controller/
    type: annotation
```

The problem is that i have an **alias** in my apache config and also a **prefix** in my Symfony project.
So, i have to do `/api/api/*` to access my api data.

How can I point my api to `/api` instead of `/api/api`.

PS : Sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Can't you just get rid of the /api prefix in your route configuration?

Comment: No because i also have to add a `/backoffice` on my project. Finally, i used proxypass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i used ProxyPass :

**My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/app-front.conf` :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app-front.local
    ServerAlias app-front.local www.app-front.local
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/app-front/build"
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    <Directory "/var/www/app-front/build">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All

        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass "/api" "http://app-back.local/api"
    ProxyPassReverse "/api" "http://app-back.local/api"

    ProxyPass "/admin" "http://app-back.local/admin"
    ProxyPassReverse "/admin" "http://app-back.local/admin"

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/app-back.conf` :**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app-back.local
    ServerAlias app-back.local www.app-back.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/app-back/public
    DirectoryIndex /index.php

    <Directory /var/www/app-back/public>
        #Require forward-dns app-front.local
        #Require forward-dns app-front.local
        AllowOverride None
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
        FallbackResource /index.php
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/app-back/public/bundles>
        FallbackResource disabled
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app_back_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app_back_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**My Symfony `config/routes/annotation.yml` :**

```
api:
    prefix: /api
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Api/
    type: annotation

backoffice:
    prefix: /admin
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Admin/
    type: annotation
```

**My `/etc/hosts` :**

```
127.0.0.1 app-back.local www.app-back.local
127.0.0.1 app-front.local www.app-front.local
```

If you have a better solution, let me know please.